# Calculate Balance Factor

Tags: java, binary-tree, avl-tree

I have an assignment, to implement a method which prints out the balance factor of all the internal nodes of the binary tree t.

I have tried to do it, but I needed three methods.. I think there should be one and I am only able to print out the balance factor of the root, I think this should be for every node of tree t?

```
public int maxHeight(BinaryTree t) {    
    if(t == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int height1 = maxHeight(t.getLeft()) + 1;

    int height2 = maxHeight(t.getRight()) + 1;

    if(height1 > height2) {
        return height1;
    }
    else {
        return height2;
    }
}

public int minHeight(BinaryTree v) {
    if(v == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int height1 = minHeight(v.getLeft()) + 1;

    int height2 = minHeight(v.getRight()) + 1;

    if(height1 < height2) {
        return height1;
    }
    else {
        return height2;
    }
}

public int balanceFactor(int max, int min) {
    return max - min;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be as simple as:

```
public int printBalanceFactor(BinaryTree t)
{
    if (t == null)
        return 0;

    if (t.left == null && t.right == null)
        return 1;

    int heightL = printBalanceFactor(t.left);
    int heightR = printBalanceFactor(t.right);

    System.out.println("Balance factor of " + t + " is " + (heightL - heightR));

    return heightL + heightR + 1;
}
```